# Why does my Angular app bind data differently than my course presenter's does?

Tags: javascript, angular

In the video [Diving Deeper into Template-based Forms](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=angular-fundamentals&author=jim-cooper&name=angular-fundamentals-m6&clip=8&mode=live)  in the [Angular Fundamentals](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-fundamentals/table-of-contents) course on Pluralsight, I am encountering a significant difference in behavior when I run the presenter's code.

The code for the Component is given at the bottom of this question. Note that it contains no properties for the model.

Also note that the an elided version of the template is provided. This is provided exactly as the presenter provided it. The `NgModel` attribute in the form refers to a `name` field from the Component, but this does not exist on the Component. When I attempt to build the code and run it, this results in compile-time errors, and the application will not run.

However, when the presenter runs the solution using exactly the same code, it runs just fine and exactly as he expects it to.

If I add backing fields to the Component, it works just fine, but then my code no longer matches his code, and there's a significant portion of this course remaining to get through.

I am puzzled by this difference in behavior. I *expect* it to fail to compile without backing fields in the Component.

Can someone explain what is going on here? I am using the most recent version of Angular as of this writing.

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { EventService } from './shared/event.service';
import { IEvent } from './shared';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './create-event.component.html',
  styles: [
    `
      em {
        float: right;
        color: #e05c65;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
      .error input {
        background-color: #e3c3c5;
      }
      .error ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: #999;
      }
      .error ::-moz-placeholder {
        color: #999;
      }
      .error :-moz-placeholder {
        color: #999;
      }
      .error :ms-input-placeholder {
        color: #999;
      }
    `,
  ],
})
export class CreateEventComponent {
  isDirty: boolean = true;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private eventService: EventService) {
  }

  saveEvent(formValues) {
    this.eventService.saveEvent(formValues);
    this.isDirty = false;
    this.router.navigate(['/events']);
  }

  cancel() {
    this.router.navigate(['/events']);
  }
}
```

*Template (Elided)*

```
<h1>New Event</h1>
<hr>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <form #newEventForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveEvent(newEventForm.value)"
    autocomplete="off" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group"
      [ngClass]="{'error': newEventForm.controls.name?.invalid && newEventForm.controls.name?.touched}">
      <label for="eventName">Event Name:</label>
      <em
        *ngIf="newEventForm.controls.name?.invalid && (newEventForm.controls.name?.touched)">Required</em>
      <input (ngModel)="name" name="name" required id="name" type="text"
        class="form-control" placeholder="Name of your event..." />
    </div>
```

Comment: double binding [(ngModel)]="name"?

Comment: @huanfeng Are you suggesting I try two-way binding? I've tried that, to no effect. In any event, that still wouldn't explain why the code above works for the presenter, but not for me, which is the truly puzzling mystery here.

Comment: @MikeHofer It is expected to have a variable of name in component, but in dev mode it is not very strict. Usually this error would when you configure to use compiler like aot usually configured for prod or stage environments. Can you tell how you are running the app and if possible share angular.json file.

Answer (score 0):

What's the output in the console? There should be some other issues.

I just create a stackblitz with your form implementation, it works well without any compiling error.

BTW, I think you should use `[(ngModel)]="name"` if you want to do the double
direction binding of the name.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-driven-form-validation-gbszme?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: No error messages appear on the console; it just silently fails (more weirdness). Also, I'm aware that banana-in-a-box syntax is for two-way data binding. That's part of the topic we're covering. The issue I'm raising here occurs whether we're using one- or two-way data binding.